# como configurar parametros en el router de angular para que el servidor IIS los reconozca

Tags: c#, angular, iis

Compañeros tengo el siguiente routing

```
RouterModule.forRoot([     
  { path: 'seguimiento', component: RequisicionComponent},
  {path:':token/:email/:nombre' ,component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'' ,component: HomeComponent},       
  
])
```

como ven el path2 recibe 3 parametros cuando ejecuto el proyecto local lo resuelve muy bien entiende cuales son los parametros
http://localhost:4200/para1/para2/para3

pero cuando despliego el proyecto en IIS no reconoce los parametros y los toma como una URL completa
me sale error:

Bad Request - Invalid URL

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias soluciones

1. usar URL basados en HASH: en el `App Module` a en `Routing Module` le puedes pasar una paremtro adicional `{ useHash: true }` a la `funcion RouterModule.forRoot`
2. Usar "reescritura de URL" lo puedes activar en el IIS Manager o en el web.config de tu aplicacion lo cual hace que no busque un match exacto de toda la ruta sino que se diriga a la pagina base
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si aplicas la opciones 2 y bajo ese sitio web de IIS tienes subsitios web que son MVC or asp.net.core te dejarian de funcionar y necesitarias agregar esta otra regla **ANTES** de de "Angular Routes" del paso 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tomado de
https://srinu-vasu289.medium.com/routing-issues-with-angular-on-iis-97478a6c47d1